# Initializing Firebase Functions Emulator For Correct Project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am developing a project with Firebase backend, utilising Firebase Functions. I actually two projects: `myProject` and `myProject-test` (used for deployment testing).

When submitting API calls, my (React) front-end is configured to call the `myProject-test` URL when running in local development, and only direct the calls to `myProject` when deployed on PROD.

The problem I am facing is that when I start my cloud functions emulator using `firebase emulators:start`, my cloud functions get started on the `localhost:5001/myProject/...` url instead of `localhost:5001/myProject-test/...`, and hence the API calls from my local development instance never arrive.

How can I control for which project the emulators start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the `firebase use` command is for.  Read the documentation on [managing aliases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#project_aliases).  You can run the command `firebase use PROJECT_ID|ALIAS` to set the current project or alias that is currently use use for the emulator or other commands.